# How Can I pass an array or add a loop in jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

Here is the function -

```
$.swipebox( [
    { href:'big/image1.jpg', title:'My Caption' }, 
    { href:'big/image2.jpg', title:'My Second Caption' }
] );
```

Instead of this I would like add a loop here or if not possible then pass an array.

Something like -

```
$.swipebox( [
  $.each( data, function(index, val){
      { href:data[index].image_link, title:data[index].image_title }            
  } )
] );
```

or something similar to this. I will be really glad if anyone could help me with that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) like

```
$.swipebox($.map(data, function (val, index) {
    return {
        href: val.image_link,
        title: val.image_title
    }
}));
```